# how to convert date in java

Tags: java, datetime, date, timestamp

I am new in android . 
I have to convert following date into this time stamp (`Wed Oct 12 14:17:42 GMT+05:30 2011`)

```
Thu, 27 May 2010 12:37:27 GMT
```

This is the date that I am getting from the server through the header. I have converted it into the String object. Now I have to convert it into the Date format like: `Wed Oct 12 14:17:42 GMT+05:30 2011`

Please could you help me how should I convert it into the (`Wed Oct 12 14:17:42 GMT+05:30 2011`) this format using timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `DateFormat` or `SimpleDateFormat` which provide `parse()` and `format()` methods. `DateFormat` provides a bunch of standard formats whereas `SimpleDateFormat` allows you to provide your own format expression.

Example for your input date:

```
//note that you need the locale as well, since the weekdays and months are written in a specific language, English in that case
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH );
SimpleDateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH );
writeFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT" ) );

Date tDate = parseFormat.parse( "Wed, 12 Oct 2011 14:17:42 GMT" );

System.out.println(writeFormat.format(tDate )); //Wed Oct 12 14:17:42 GMT 2011
```

Edit: If you want a more usable API, try [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).